# How to create a status bar in a dialog?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, atl, statusbar, wtl

How do I display a `CStatusBarCtrl` inside a dialog class (inheriting from `CDialogImpl`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special - you create the window, with the proper owner (the dialog), and you put it into proper position... Just like any other control created from code.

Comment: But how do I get it working for dialogs? Frames are easy, but I'm not sure what the best way to put it in a dialog is.

Comment: Your answer to my other question works for this, so if you'd like, mention the solution here and I'll accept it! :)

Comment: OK, so the thread which actually helped to sort thi status bar question out is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324153/how-to-create-a-splitter-in-atl-wtl/7352354#7352354